# Test/programming rig with spring-loaded probes/connectors

Tags: probe, production-testing, testbench

I have ESP32-CAM module with two rows of 0.1" male pins. The pins are 0.22" high. Here is a picture:

[image]

I would like to trim them, so they are too short to mate with the corresponding female header. I'm looking for spring-loaded probes/connectors I can solder to a test/programming fixture, which will interface with short pin stubs. I'm not looking for parts recommendation, which is probably not allowed here. Just a technical term for this device would do, so I can google the specifics myself.

Comment: Why can't you use the normal female headers soldered to your test fixture?

Comment: Pogo pins are the male version, but getting them to align correctly with probably-unevenly-cut header ends is going to be a nightmare.  Try looking for rectangular spring loaded connectors; those come in 0.1" pitch to match your pins.

Comment: @vir There are also pogo pins with a cup at the end instead of a point, works a treat to interface with pin headers like this. The head comes in lots of different models.

Comment: @Andyaka In my post: *I would like to trim them, so they are too short to mate with the corresponding female header*

Comment: Oh... you mean you HAVE to trim them (for whatever reason) rendering them useless for a normal female header.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. In the meantime, I found a low profile female header, which should work with 0.05" long or even shorter pins: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/3M-Electronic-Solutions-Division/929870-01-09-RA?qs=neFkstNq%252B6FfvS%2FRxqE1Pw%3D%3D&mgh=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAuvOPBhDXARIsAKzLQ8F-sDCIbIl-QHJVjRZH0qSdi2fe0_WNzAg-hFStPJJEkT-8VKfcnFkaAhbFEALw_wcB. It should work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is spring loaded pins

[image]
Source: https://www.mouser.com/new/mill-max/mill-max-contactsandprobes/

This is probably what you are looking for

[image]
Source: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp./816-22-006-10-001101/6149708?utm_adgroup=Rectangular%20Connectors%20-%20Spring%20Loaded&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Connectors%2C%20Interconnects_NEW&utm_term=&utm_content=Rectangular%20Connectors%20-%20Spring%20Loaded&gclid=Cj0KCQiAuvOPBhDXARIsAKzLQ8G_BLEcBtef8D93clX26SYYhV3tr9hzjB2TB9jKiLpgQ7f3qAWkLQwaAh8EEALw_wcB)

Here is another [link](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/contacts-spring-loaded-pogo-pins-and-pressure/311?s=N4IgTCBcDaIA4HsDmCAEcCWA7AziAugL5A)

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated.